# Possible Data corruption after compression in MSVC? (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, compression

I am somewhat new to C++, and am toying around with basic compression. I have written the program below in MSVC (Windows 7, compiled as 32 bit console program), which compresses the char array with 4 possible values into a single byte. I have included lines of code to check the intermediary binary values.

(Apologies for the long code below, the only include is iostream)

When the program is run:

ABCD is converted to 11100100, which is correct according to my encoding table. 
This converts on my system to ASCII ý.

However, when decoded, ý becomes 11101100 which decodes as "ADCD"! I have tried a few other starting arrays, and the corruption seems to only occur when the second character in the array is a "B", when it then gets changed to a "D", or if there is a string of all "B"s, when the alternate "B"s get changed to "D"s. When placed at other locations, "B" does not get corrupted.

I am perplexed as to why one bit will be in error, and only for specific sequences, if anyone could give me some tips?

Thanks!

K

```
struct CompressedChar {
    int firstbit; 
    int secondbit; 
};


CompressedChar Encoder(char baseinput)
{
CompressedChar bitoutput;

switch (baseinput)
    {
    case 'A':
        bitoutput.firstbit = 0;
        bitoutput.secondbit = 0;
        break;
    case 'B':
        bitoutput.firstbit = 1;
        bitoutput.secondbit = 0;
        break;
    case 'C':
        bitoutput.firstbit = 0;
        bitoutput.secondbit = 1;
        break;
    case 'D':
        bitoutput.firstbit = 1;
        bitoutput.secondbit = 1;
        break;

    }   

return bitoutput;
}


char Decoder(int firstbit, int secondbit)
{
if (firstbit == 0)
{
    if (secondbit == 0)
        return 'A';
    else if (secondbit == 1)
        return 'C';
}

else if (firstbit == 1)
{
    if (secondbit == 0)
        return 'B';
    else if (secondbit = 1)
        return 'D';
}

return '0';
}

int main()
{
char a[4] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};

char output;


for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
{
    CompressedChar bitoutput;

    bitoutput = Encoder(a[(i/2)]);

    std::cout << bitoutput.firstbit;
    std::cout << bitoutput.secondbit;

    if (bitoutput.firstbit == 1)
        { output |= (1 << i); }
    else if (bitoutput.firstbit == 0)
        { output &= ~(1 << i);}

    if (bitoutput.secondbit == 1)
        { output |= (1 << (i + 1) ); }
    else if (bitoutput.firstbit == 0)
        { output &= ~(1 << (i + 1));}
}

std::cout << std::endl << output << std::endl;

char b[4];
int temp1, temp2;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
{
    temp1 = (output >> i) & 1;
    temp2 = (output >> (i + 1)) & 1;

    std::cout<< temp1;
    std::cout<< temp2;

    b[i/2] = Decoder(temp1, temp2);
} 

    std::cout<< std::endl;
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j ++)
{
    std::cout << b[j];
}

std::cout << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of what it was getting initialized to 0xCC. You may also have made a mistake on line that says "else if (bitoutput.firstbit == 0)" should be secondbit. Also make output unsigned char to be safe/clear.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed! I knew I must have done something careless...although, I still don't understand why the errors were specific to just the "B" character.

Comment: It's because of what it was getting initialized to 0xCC. You may also have made a mistake on line that says "else if (bitoutput.firstbit == 0)" should be secondbit. Also make output unsigned char to be safe/clear.